# I want to plot 3D and set the view. what is the unit of ax.dist?

Tags: matplotlib, 3d, distance

the distance between my object and the camera is 18 centimeters. But the result is not right.

my code is

```
ax= figure.gca(projection="3d")
ax.view_init(elev= 130, azim = 12)
ax.dist=18
```

What is the unit of ax.dist?

Answer (score 4):

`ax.dist` does not have any units. It's a relative factor for the projections. The default value is `ax.dist = 10`, smaller values make the unit cube appear closer, while larger values make it appear further away.